# Multiple inheritance without virtual functions in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

I came across the diamond problem and found different solutions for different cases with a single diamond. However I couldn't find a solution for 'chained' diamonds.

According to the structure: yes, I want to have multiple baseclasses everytime, so virtual inheritance isn't a solution (is it even called diamond then?). I also wanted to avoid get/set-functions for every middle-layer of a diamond.

```
p   p
|   |
k   k
 \ /
  s

class parent { int val; };
class kid1 : public parent {};
class kid2 : public parent {};
class school : public kid1, public kid2 {};
```

Accessing val in the parent class works now like follows:

```
school* s = new school;
s->kid1::val=1; // works
```

But what about the next 'chained' diamond:

```
p   p   p   p
|   |   |   |
k   k   k   k
 \ /     \ /
  s       s
  |       |
  c       c
    \   /
      w

class country1 : public school {};
class country2 : public school {};
class world : public country1, public country2 {};
```

Accessing val via:

```
world* w = new world;
w->country1::kid1::val=1; // error
```

results in:

```
error: ‘kid1’ is an ambiguous base of ‘world’
```

Why? Isn't the route to the value well defined?

Comment: @Nikolay: I think @nem knows that. But for each country we have an unambiguous base kid1. Hence the question, why this doesn't work

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `school : kid` relationship violates the LSP. At least I have never been to a school that was two kids :)

Comment: I fear for the sanity of whoever ends up maintaining this code base - it even drove poor Visual Studio insane. The IDE registers this as an error, but the compiler doesn't.

Comment: this was just hypothetical :) i have a different implementation.

Comment: @Fred, @Jon: agreed, it would be much better to use composition here than inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s->kid1::val` does not mean "`val` from the `kid1` subobject".  It's just a name qualified by the type (not the subobject) that contains it.

I don't know why `country1::kid1` is even accepted at all, but apparently it's a typedef for `::kid1`.  Two data members in `world` both have the qualified name `::kid1::val`.

What you want is:

```
world* w = new world;
country1* const c1 = world;
c1->kid1::val = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is.  The error is due to a bug in your compiler.

Comment: Considering I've already explained why the code is wrong, any claim the code is right should come with a citation of the particular part of the C++ standard that you think allows it :)

Comment: §3.4.3 Qualified name lookup is quite clear.  Given
w->country1::kid1::val, the compiler uses §3.4.5 Class member access to
look up country1; according to §3.4.5/4, if the id-expression is
a qualified-id (it is), this lookup takes place in both the class scope,
and the context of the complete expression, so the compiler finds
::country1.  Following that, the usual rules in §3.4.3 apply.

Comment: @James: And then the rule is applied again (there are two scope resolution operators), and the compiler finds `::kid1` (as I said in my answer).  But `::kid1::val` is ambiguous, the compiler is correct.  There is no `country1::kid1` apart from `::kid1`, scope resolution operators work on type names, not subobject names (and base subobjects aren't named, so you can't say `w->country1.kid1.val`).

Comment: @Ben Voigt Which rule?  After the compiler has found country1, it's in
a qualified name lookup (§3.4.3), and doesn't (or shouldn't) look
anywhere but in country1.

Comment: @James: What is `w->country1::kid1`?  A type?  Then `w->country1::kid1::val` is ambiguous, because that type is twice a base class of `world`.  A subobject?  Then it's illegal to follow it with `::`.

Comment: Good question:-).  It's clearly a type (since regardless of how
you look for it, kid1 is a class).  On the other hand, this sort
of thing has always worked in C++, since the days of CFront; if
it doesn't work today, then there is probably a problem in the
wording of the standard.

Comment: @James: I'd be convinced if you can provide a code sample that compiles under Comeau.  But I think this code truly is ambiguous.

Comment: @Ben Voigt My experience with this dates to a bit before Comeau; earlier compilers handled it as I described.  But I've not tried lately; as my C++ skills improved, I found that designs requiring it were generally not good ones.

Comment: @BenVoigt the same code as the OP asked fully compiles in VS2012. besides country1::kid1 is not ambiguous at all, since when you are in some classes scope, all it's parents or grand parents are available. meaning kid1 should be available in country1 scope.

Comment: @Gajoo: The Microsoft C++ compiler is known to not follow the Standard very closely.  The typename `kid` is available, certainly.  But there are two subobjects of that type, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: @BenVoigt there is only one class named `kid1` no one is saying anything about typename `kid` since there is none available at all. and of course there are two `kid1` sub objects available in the world class but `country1::kid1` is unique.

Comment: @Gajoo: `country1::kid1` is not unique.  `kid1`, `country1::kid1`, and `country2::kid1` are all names for the same type.  And yes, I meant `kid1` not `kid` in my prior comment.