# Private base class and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++

Consider :

```
struct A { int x;};
struct B : A {};
struct C : private A {};
```

Now, as expected, the code

```
struct D : C
{
    D () { C::x = 2; }
};

int main () { D d; }
```

does not compile:

```
test2.cc: In constructor ‘D::D()’:
test2.cc:1:16: error: ‘int A::x’ is inaccessible
test2.cc:7:12: error: within this context
```

Now, if I do

```
struct D : B, C
{
    D () { C::x = 2; }
};

int main () { D d; }
```

then the error disappear! Isn't `A::x` supposed to be inaccessible too? What is the explanation here?

I'm using `gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC)`, linux x86_64, if this matters.

**EDIT:** It does not compile with Clang 3.2: [clang 3.2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/188WMz$74)

But it does with gcc 4.7.2: [gcc 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/clone/VvWyUW)

Comment: Compiles [there](http://ideone.com/clone/VvWyUW) (same compiler though). Seems a GCC bug then?

Comment: Interesting: same compiler, different outcome. I can't think of anything else than a bug anyway

Comment: g++ 4.7.2 compiles the same source in both locations successfully.

Comment: Me dumb. Bad copy-paste. Sorry

Comment: [there](http://liveworkspace.org/code/188WMz$74) is the Clang output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple inheritance without virtual functions in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353291/multiple-inheritance-without-virtual-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most certainly a **bug**. There is no reason why inheriting from class `B` as well should change the accessibility of `C`'s members.

Not even GCC 4.8.0 (beta) seems to have solved this problem. Clang 3.2 and ICC 13.0.1, on the other hand, [correctly refuse to compile this code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/188WMz%2473).

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk: I dunno, `C::x` pretty clearly scopes to `C`.

Comment: @GManNickG: Are you sure?  That names `A::x`.  It does not name the `C` subobject.  If you want to name a member of the `C` subobject, use `C* p = this; p->x`

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't get it: `C::x` should be resolved into `C::A::x`, or am I missing something? It seems GCC resolves it into `B::A::x` instead, which makes no sense

Comment: btw, static casting `*this` to `(C&)` and trying to access `x` that way fails: http://ideone.com/34Chr3, so this is specific to access via scope-resolution

Comment: @StephenLin: Indeed it seems to be a scope resolution issue.

Comment: @Andy: It is resolved into `C::A::x`.  Which is `A::x`.  Which is ambiguous, but only one `A::x` is accessible.  The part before a scope resolution operator names a type, not a subobject.

Comment: @BenVoigt I might be misunderstanding you, but I think `C::x` is supposed to refer specifically to the `A::x` in the `C` subobject and not be ambiguous, see [this](http://ideone.com/Bj1DJn) as an example

Comment: @Stephen: Where is that described in the Standard?

Comment: @BenVoight 10.1 p5 (in draft N3242, last public draft before C++11) "In such lattices, explicit qualification can be used to specify which subobject is meant. The body of function
`C::f` could refer to the member next of each `L` subobject:
`void C::f() { A::next = B::next; }` Without the `A::` or `B::` qualifiers, the definition of `C::f` above would be ill-formed because of ambiguity" ("such lattices" referring to multiple inheritance hierarchies where a base class is present more than once)

Comment: @StephenLin: `C::x` is ambiguous according to lookup rules, however a compiler is allowed to resolve the ambiguity because it is qualified (see my answer). The wording is `can often be resolved`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is clang is correct. However, the code could also fail as ambiguous according to the standard.

If you look at 11.2p5 it has a relevant note (yes, I know notes are non-normative):

> [ Note: This class can be explicit, e.g., when a qualified-id is used,
>   or implicit, e.g., when a class member access operator (5.2.5) is used
>   (including cases where an implicit “this->” is added). **If both a class
>   member access operator and a qualified-id are used to name the member
>   (as in `p->T::m`), the class naming the member is the class denoted by
>   the nested-name-specifier of the qualified-id (that is, T)**. —end note
>   ]

What this note means, is that if you add `this->` to `C::x = 2;` then `C` is the class naming the member and [gcc 4.7.2 correctly fails when this is the case](http://liveworkspace.org/code/F2wWf%240).

Now the question is **Who is the class naming the member for** `C::x`?
The `naming class` is specified by the same `11.2p5`:

> The access to a member is affected by the class in which the member is
>   named. **This naming class is the class in which the member name was
>   looked up and found.**

Now, name lookup for class members is specified in 10.2, and after reading all of it, I have concluded that `x` is the **union** of subobject sets as per:

> Otherwise, the new S(f, C) is a lookup set with the shared set of
>   declarations and the union of the subobject sets.

Which means that according to member lookup rules `x` can be either from `B` *or* `A`! This makes the code ill-formed as: `Name
lookup can result in an ambiguity, in which case the program is ill-formed.`
However, this ambiguity **can** be resolved as per 10.2p8:

> Ambiguities can often be resolved by qualifying a name with its class
>   name.

And from the [Clang source](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Sema/SemaExpr.cpp?sortby=rev&r1=97677&r2=97676&pathrev=97677), we can see that is what they chose to do:

```
// If the member was a qualified name and the qualified referred to a
// specific base subobject type, we'll cast to that intermediate type
// first and then to the object in which the member is declared. That allows
// one to resolve ambiguities in, e.g., a diamond-shaped hierarchy such as:
//
//   class Base { public: int x; };
//   class Derived1 : public Base { };
//   class Derived2 : public Base { };
//   class VeryDerived : public Derived1, public Derived2 { void f(); };
//   void VeryDerived::f() {
//     x = 17; // error: ambiguous base subobjects
//     Derived1::x = 17; // okay, pick the Base subobject of Derived1
//   }
```

However, note the `can` in the wording of the above quote: `often can be resolved`. This means that **they do not necessarily have to be resolved**. So, I think according to the standard the code should fail as ambiguous or as a private member access failure.

**EDIT**

There is some contention about the interpretation of `can` and as to whether a ambiguity occurs here. I found [Defect report 39. Conflicting ambiguity rules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#39) talks about this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your reading, did you see the example of in 10.1 p5? It seems clear that even without `this->` there is not meant to be any ambiguity. (The case there is almost exactly the same as the ones cited in the question and your answer.)

Comment: @StephenLin: Note the wording `can be used`. I interpret that as meaning it is **not** mandatory.

Comment: I believe the word "can" here means that the situation "can be resolved" if the qualified-id is provided if the qualified-id resolves to a subobject for which there is only one member of that name (but might not be, if given the qualified-id there are still multiple subobjects with the same member name), not that the standard allows discretion on whether or not to resolve it. I would find it very unusual if the standard really gave implementations discretion on a basic compile-time semantic issue, rather than simply unspecified runtime behavior.

Comment: so the "can" is indicating logical possibility, not giving discretion...also, there is no note on the example of 10.1 p5 that says the behavior is optional, it says specifically that it is "well-formed" as a comment

Comment: @StephenLin: While I understand your interpretation, I believe they would use stronger wording if they wanted to make it mandatory. There is no reason why they use the wording `can` here except to give discretion.

Comment: you can see what others think, but I'm really quite sure it's about logical possibility

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure of the exact cause but i know this:

when you use multiple inheritance in a diamond pattern like this one, you will have multiple copies of the base class A in you derived object D.

In your case the object D has 2 members named A::x which may cause confusion from the compiler.

this is known as the [Diamon Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)

Comment: What does the diamond problem have to do with this question? The only scenario in which he creates a diamond-shaped inheritance graph is the second one, which he says works fine!